# Windows Run dialog box with increased width?

Tags: windows-7, run-dialog

The Windows **Run** dialog box obviously is made for stamp-size monitors, as in Windows 7 the **Run** dialog box has a width of only 413 pixel. This makes it impossible to see a longer command line without horizontal scrolling. It also makes it impossible to see (and compare) a longer command line in the history drop down menu.

So how can I increase the width of the Windows **Run** dialog box? Or is there a custom **Run** dialog box with increased width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a program called "Resize Enable" that allows you to resize any dialog box in Windows.

http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/downloads.html

There is the link for it.  It has no UI, just install it, run it, and it sits in the background and allows you to resize any dialog box.